# What is the comparative of the adjective "manual"?

Tags: adjectives, comparative

I am wondering what is the comparative of "manual", the adjective that expresses doing something involving or using human effort.

Is it correct to say: "If you want want to achieve that task, you should do something more manual"? and a side question: should I use "manually" instead of "manual" in this case?

Comment: There really isn't such a thing. If something isn't fully automatic, and not fully manual, then often it's described with other adjectives -- such as "power brakes" in cars.

Comment: Manual means 'relating to or done with the hands'. There isn't a comparative except, "Use BOTH hands". Or perhaps you need "Try harder" or "Put your back into it!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you want want to achieve that task, you should do something more manual.

This is correct.

*Manually* turns *manual* into an adverb - which doesn't work.

However, the word *manual* when used like this might have a strong connotation of "blue-collar labor" - working on cars, building houses, literally getting your hands dirty, etc.

An option is to use it's antonym *automated* - e.g. "you should do something less automated."

Comment: Good point about using a (negated / diminished) antonym. I can't think of examples offhand, but I'm sure there will be *many* contexts in English where ***less/more [antonym]*** would be far more idiomatic than ***more/less [synonym]***.

Comment: Thank you @LawrenceC. Great and clear answer.